# Dropping a 1000 lb anvil on a foe with telekinesis

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, magic

One of my players wants to drop a 1000 lb anvil on top of an enemy, using the telekinesis spell.

How should I adjudicate?

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate. Using telekinesis to drop a 1000 lb anvil on an enemy doesn't seem like an automatic hit. The higher it's dropped, the more damage it does, but maybe the more chance for the enemy to dodge. So maybe there are a few things to adjudicate due to the telekinesis portion of the question, aside from the damage portion. Then there's the question of where did the 1000 lb anvil come from? Was it laying around? Or did they have it in a bag of holding or similar?

Comment: Please clarify ... is the target a coyote?

Comment: Comments are to be used to improve and get the question reopened, it's not an excuse for answering in comments.  The comment answer was flagged and has been deleted.

Comment: @jack nah, the answer there is good for me. This is a dupe.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast it is a Red Wizard of Thay, these days they account to almost the same.